# LINQ query to dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to convert below LINQ query result into dictionary

```
var browser = (from tbf in context.tblFeedBacks
                        where tbf.email == dboard.userEmail
                        select tbf).GroupBy(l => l.browser)
                        .Select(g => new
                        {
                            browser = g.Key,
                            count = g.Select(l => l.browser).Distinct().Count()
                        });
```

It gives me a compilation error.

```
var browser = (from tbf in context.tblFeedBacks
                            where tbf.email == dboard.userEmail
                            select tbf).GroupBy(l => l.browser)
                            .Select(g => new
                            {
                                browser = g.Key,
                                count = g.Select(l => l.browser).Distinct().Count()
                            }).ToDictionary<string, double>(x => x.browser,y=>y.count);
```

> Instance argument: cannot convert from
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable' to
>   'System.Linq.ParallelQuery'

Comment: Probably use have using statement that imports some types from Parallel library that have extension methods similar to Select or GroupBy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

got it working.

```
var browser = (from tbf in context.tblFeedBacks
                            where tbf.email == dboard.userEmail
                            select tbf).GroupBy(l => l.browser)
                            .Select(g => new
                            {
                                browser = g.Key,
                                count = g.Select(l => l.browser).Count()
                            }).ToDictionary(x => x.browser, x => x.count);
```